# Single Vert: CTRL + Right-Click opens different program

Tags: vertices

I am learning how to create a series of streets with intersections in Blender, but when I press CTRL and right-click the mouse button, instead of adding vertices, it opened a different program while Blender was still on!

Any way I can fix this?

Comment: Usually the keyboard shortcuts from the OS take precedence over those in blender. What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10.  And if it is Windows 10, how do I fix it?

Comment: @susu Could you please reply whenever you get a chance?

Comment: I don't use windows. What is the program that opens when you press Ctrl +RMB? There has to  be an option to disable that shortcut somewhere in the preferences of that program or on the mouse or keyboard preferences.